# Iam creating a poker game in Flash AS3, what are the best design patterns I can use?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, media

Iam creating a Flash AS3 based Poker game for my company. Some like zynga poker, what are the best design patterns that I can use in my game.

All suggestions are welcome, I am looking to create a good designed game which can support huge number of players.

Comment: Iam documenting everything here
http://sumitghosh.co.in/category/online-gaming/multiplayer-poker/

If anyone is of the same interest as me they can comment and colloborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Model View Controller pattern would work well.

"The pattern isolates business logic from input and presentation"

I would say the PureMVC framework is the most popular implementation of this pattern for AS3 followed by Cairngorm.

Comment: Awesome I had not heard of Mate before. Seems like it is the way to go. I must say I never really liked PureMVC much from the little I have had to do with it but there wasn't much else at the time.

Comment: PureMVC is just too,cool any good samples of poker implementations which use it?

Answer (score 3):

Huge number of players? That won't have anything to do with the flash portion, hopefully. You'll want a beefy server to handle game transactions and the like, although I guess you could rig some sort of peer to peer system up where the server did little more than list hosts.

Comment: Flash portion will have to handle the steady stream of updates from other clients either through polling or socket communication. This is necessarily trivial.

Comment: Yes I agree we need a good server, Smartfox and Flash Media Server are our choices. But coding best practices are trivial irrespective of servers.